# Export member from a chatter group not present in an another group

Tags: apex, reporting, chatter, chatter-groups, collaborationgroup

I have 2 chatter's groups, i would like to export the users present in the group A and not present in the group B.

I have tried with custom report, but i have not access to Collaboration Group Member.

I try to do with query :

```
SELECT MemberId, Member.Name, CollaborationGroup.Name 
 FROM  CollaborationGroupMember 
 WHERE CollaborationGroup.Name = 'Groupe A' 
   AND MemberId NOT IN (SELECT MemberId FROM CollaborationGroupMember 
                         WHERE CollaborationGroup.Name = 'Group 2')
```

But it not authorized to request the same object.

With apex code that be possible :

```
Set<Id> idMemberGroupB = new Set<Id>();

for(CollaborationGroupMember member : [SELECT MemberId FROM CollaborationGroupMember 
                                        WHERE CollaborationGroup.Name = 'Group B']){
    idMemberCIB.add(member.MemberId);
}
System.debug([SELECT MemberId, Member.Name, CollaborationGroup.Name 
                FROM CollaborationGroupMember 
               WHERE CollaborationGroup.Name = 'RCC 2.0' 
                 AND MemberId NOT IN :idMemberGroupB ]);
```

But it's not simple for users.

Someone has an idea  ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you license Conga Composer, you can generate excel/word/pdf reports from queries

Comment: I dont have licence Conga Composer